# Regular expressions: choose those rows in which the same word is repeated 3 or more times within the same sentence

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a table with a text column, and from this I need to choose those rows in which the same word is repeated 3 or more times within the same sentence, with which I- and I are different words.
The following is what I did but it does not work properly.
One letter is a word, but there can be many letters.
The end of the sentence is the symbols (dot,!,?)

```
select *
from text
where regexp_like(text,
 q'~([^[:alpha:]-]|^)
([[:alpha:]]{2,}(-[[:alpha:]]{2,})?|-[[:alpha:]]{2,}|[[:alpha:]]{2,}-)
[^[:alpha:]-]((.*?[^[:alpha:]-])?\2([^[:alpha:]-]|$)){2,}~','ix');
```

sample text:

```
-bad girls, -bad boys,-bad phone. phone phone mam: phone phone? 
wup, wup, BORAK OBAMA OBAMA MAMA; it is OBAMA . 
hustone, we have a problem, big problem. Very big, big, big
high cost - high perfomance, high 
full-hd,tv-full,full-hd:full-hd
Fooo fooo fooo , fooo-- fooo-- 
fooo feee faaa , fooo-fooo, fooo-fooo.
 a a a 
A. a a
```

Comment: Is this a MySQL or an Oracle database?

Comment: Oracle database , sorry I'm using the forum for the first time

Comment: That's fine; just be careful what you use to tag future questions with - it can confuse the issue if you include irrelevant tags, leading to people wasting their and your time with clarifying questions. Thanks for including your query and sample data, though *{:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to search for:

- `(^|[^[:alpha:]-])` The start of the string or a non-word character;
- `([[:alpha:]-]+)` Then a word made up of your word characters;
- `(`

  - `[^[:alpha:]-.!?]` Followed by a non-sentence end, non-word character;
  - `([^.!?]*[^[:alpha:]-.!?])?` Then, optionally, any number of non-sentence end characters follows by a non-sentence end, non-word character;
  - `\2` Then the previously matched word
- `){2}` repeated twice;
- `($|[^[:alpha:]-])` and finally either the end-of-the-string or a non-word character.

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db504/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE strings ( value ) AS
SELECT '-bad girls, -bad boys,-bad phone. phone phone mam: phone phone? ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'wup, wup, BORAK OBAMA OBAMA MAMA; it is OBAMA . ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'hustone, we have a problem, big problem. Very big, big, big' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'high cost - high perfomance, high ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'full-hd,tv-full,full-hd:full-hd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fooo fooo fooo , fooo-- fooo-- ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fooo feee faaa , fooo-fooo, fooo-fooo.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT ' a a a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A. a a' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value, 
         '(^|[^[:alpha:]-])([[:alpha:]-]+)([^[:alpha:]-.!?]([^.!?]*[^[:alpha:]-.!?])?\2){2}($|[^[:alpha:]-])',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         2
       ) As match
FROM   strings
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         value,
         '(^|[^[:alpha:]-])([[:alpha:]-]+)([^[:alpha:]-.!?]([^.!?]*[^[:alpha:]-.!?])?\2){2}($|[^[:alpha:]-])'
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db504/5/0)**:

```
|                                                            VALUE |   MATCH |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|---------|
| -bad girls, -bad boys,-bad phone. phone phone mam: phone phone?  |    -bad |
|                 wup, wup, BORAK OBAMA OBAMA MAMA; it is OBAMA .  |   OBAMA |
|      hustone, we have a problem, big problem. Very big, big, big |     big |
|                               high cost - high perfomance, high  |    high |
|                                  full-hd,tv-full,full-hd:full-hd | full-hd |
|                                                            a a a |       a |
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the least one.
One letter is also considered a word.
I , I , I true 
I. i i False 
I I . I false

Comment: @Pol.ka You can see from the last match that this works for single letter words. If this is not what you want then [Edit Your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52406162/edit) to include the expected output as your previous comment is not clear.

Comment: And wup-wup  , wup- , -wup Different words